# Hanging indents for \section headings

Tags: sectioning, indentation, sections-paragraphs

Sometimes, I do have long section headings that take more than one line. **I would like to make second and each subsequent line of `\section` heading indented** (so called 'hanging indent'). I know I can produce hanging indent for paragraphs with `hanging` package:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hanging}

\begin{document}

\hangpara{3em}{1} \lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

However, I have no idea how to do the same for `\section` heading as `hanging` package works only for paragraphs and not headings. My code for section heading so far:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section*{\large{Very long section heading that takes two or more lines when it is typeset on page}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `titlesec` package inspired by @egreg's comment.

The title text is indented by extra 1em.
For the first line, this extra indentation is cancelled by `\hspace{-1em}`.
With section number:

```
      <-- -1em
1.1   The first line of title
         the second line...
   -----> 2em
```

Without section number:

```
<-- -1em
The first line of title
   the second line...
--> 1em
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{2em}{\hspace{-1em}}{}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{1em}{\hspace{-1em}}{}
\titleformat{name=\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{2em}{\hspace{-1em}}{}
\titleformat{name=\subsection,numberless}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{1em}{\hspace{-1em}}{}
\titleformat{name=\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{2em}{\hspace{-1em}}{}
\titleformat{name=\subsubsection,numberless}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{1em}{\hspace{-1em}}{}

\begin{document}

\section*{Very long section heading that takes two or more lines when it is typeset on page}
\subsection*{Very long section heading that takes two or more lines when it is typeset on page}
\subsubsection*{Very long section heading that takes two or more lines when it is typeset on page}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Section headings are controlled by internal commands such as `\@startsection`.
Thus, you have to modify these commands.
I redefined `\@startsection` so that it receives an additional argument (the 4th argument) which defines the amount of hanging indent.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% \@startsection{name}{level}{indent}{hangindent}{beforeskip}
%   {afterskip}{style}*[altheading]{heading}
% New argument: hangindent
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}}}}

\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6#7[#8]#9{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #6\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #7{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \advance\hangindent by #4\relax
          \interlinepenalty \@M #9\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#8}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #8}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #7{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #9}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#8}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #8}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#6}}

\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #5{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #1}%
          \advance\hangindent by #2\relax
          \interlinepenalty \@M #6\@@par}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{#5{\hskip #1\relax #6}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#4}}

\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{1em}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}{1em}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{1em}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{1em}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\parindent}{1em}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{Very long section heading that takes two or more lines when it is typeset on page}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If you want to change the amount of hanging indent, change the 4th argument of `\@startsection` in the definition of the relevant section command.
I.e. If you want to increase the hanging indent of `\section` to 5em,
replace

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{1em}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

with

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{5em}% <-- 5em
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

Comment: Do you think there is any more straightforward way of doing this (other than re-defining ``\@startsection``)?

Comment: @Rafal I think suggestion from @egreg (using `titlesec`) is a better solution.

Comment: I agree that ``titlesec``solution is better (easier one) so I marked it as accepted answer, but your original answer was interesting too.